# Execution plan - cost of sort

Tags: sql-server, performance-tuning

I've got a procedure with a Sort operator of  92%.
Here is the execution plan:
[image]
here is the script:

```
CREATE   PROCEDURE [Specification].[GetSpecificationsByPage]  
(  
  @Next int,  
        @Limit int  
)  
AS  
BEGIN  
 SELECT   
 ps.Id
 psdc.Timestamp,  
 ps.CreationStatusId,  
 ps.ErrorReason  
 FROM   
 [Specification].[Specifications] ps WITH (NOLOCK)   
 OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 psd.Timestamp  
      FROM Specification.SpecificationDetails psd  WITH (NOLOCK)  
      WHERE psd.SpecificationId =  ps.Id  
      ORDER BY psd.Timestamp) psdc  
  
 ORDER BY ps.[Id] asc  
 offset @Next rows  
 fetch next @Limit rows only  
END
```

I've added an index for column SpecificationId for table :Specification.SpecificationDetails
that includes column: Timestamp
even added index for Timestamp asc
but it still have the cost of 92%.

The only way i've got is to replace to :
ORDER BY ps.Id
or remove the line in the select:
psdc.Timestamp

what index do i need to continute?

Comment: Have you tried a composite index on `Specification.SpecificationDetails(Id, Timestamp)`? Be aware than `NOLOCK` can cause rows to get missed or duplicated during scans, causing wrong results.

Comment: Thanks

forgot that option.

Comment: Does the `Timestamp` column allow duplicate values? If so, you may need to add `Id` as a secondary ordering element to get deterministic results, though with all the `NOLOCK` hints you seem to not care about result correctness anyway.

Comment: Your query runs in 0s. Why do you want to make your database do more work maintaining an index at no additional performance gains for this query?

Comment: The Timestamp column is not unique. about the 0s it's a performance issue, it runs in 60ms and has execution count of 20K in an hour.

Comment: @dexon "*about the 0s it's a performance issue, it runs in 60ms*" - Is the execution plan you presented not the actual query? How are you sure the sort is the bottleneck?

Answer (score 3):

The `SORT` operator after each seek iteration can be avoided with a composite index:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_SpecificationDetails_Id_Timestamp ON 
    Specification.SpecificationDetails(Id, Timestamp);
```

The leftmost `Id` in the index key will facilitate the seek (as in the current plan). The `Timestamp` key column will allow an ordered scan in the seek operator, eliminating the need for a subsequent `SORT` to satisfy the `TOP 1...ORDER BY Timestamp` criteria.